# Does Islam allow the sale of Muslim real estate to a Jew?

Tags: islamic-basis, business

In Israel, Hamas doesn't allow Palestinians to sell their houses to Jews.  I'm wondering if this is based on Islam.

CORRECTION: it’s the PA that doesn’t allow sale to Jews.

Comment: Hamas's prohibition is probably due to political circumstances. I've never heard an Islamic prohibition of such a thing. But, a ruler can decide to forbid things if he notices there is some benefit in that.

Comment: In Islam, responsibility comes before the law, a Muslim has the option to temporarily hold a law if there's a danger on people saftey, examples like Omar Ibn Al-Khattab [RA] when he held the law of stealing during a famine, and also this Hadeeth: https://sunnah.com/abudawud:337

Answer (score 4):

The general rule is that a Muslim can sell anything to anyone. There are some exceptions to this, one of which is that a thing can not be sold when the purpose of the buyer is to do something haram by it. And among them is sale of some items to disbelievers who are at war with the Muslims and could use the item against the Muslims.

In the case of Palestine it is not considered permissible to sell the land to the Jews since it causes harm to the Muslim cause and strengthens Israel's claims.

> عن الشاطبي: أن بيع الشمع لهم ممنوع، إذا كانوا يستعينون به على إضرار المسلمين
>
> Al-Shaatibi said: (Even) selling them a candle is forbidden, if it helps them in causing harm to the Muslims
>
> <sup>— [شرح الكبير للشيخ الدردير وحاشية الدسوقي](https://shamela.ws/book/21604/1090)</sup>

Fatwas which prohibit the sale of Palestinian land have been given by various scholars at various times, even before Hamas existed. Below are references to some of these:

**Ref:**

- https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/134134/
- https://archive.org/details/ImdadulFatawaAshrafAliThanviDeobandi3/page/n59/mode/2up